# Notificações em tempo determinado e ao ligar celular

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Olá.
Estou fazendo um app android que me notifica quando tenho que entregar uma tarefa de escola e, caso seja o dia da tarefa ou um dia antes, quero ser notificado em certos horários.

A tela inicial é onde o service é iniciado, onde clico em "Tarefas" para ir pra Activity de tarefas.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_activity);

    startService(new Intent(this, ShowNotificationService.class));
}
}
```

Mas eu gostaria que o serviço fosse iniciado quando o celular fosse ligado (como o Whatsapp mostra notificações de mensagens quando ligamos o celular).

Código do `showNotificationService.class`

```
public class ShowNotificationService extends Service {

private EducInDAO dao;
private DatabaseHelper helper;
private Context context;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        tarefas();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void tarefas() throws ParseException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tarefas", null);

    if (cursor == null) {

    } else {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date dataEntrega = new Date(cursor.getLong(2));
            Date dateNow = new Date();

            String dataEntregaFormatada = sdf.format(dataEntrega);
            String dateNowFormatada = sdf.format(dataEntrega);

            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            int hora = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);


            if ((dateNowFormatada.compareTo(dataEntregaFormatada) == 0) || (dateNowFormatada.compareTo(dataEntregaFormatada) == 1)) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String nomeMateria = cursor.getString(1);

                String title = "Eae, já fez?";

                if ((dateNowFormatada.compareTo(dataEntregaFormatada) == 0)) {
                    if ((hora == 0 || hora == 7 || hora == 12 || hora == 23)) {
                        if ((hora == 0 || hora == 7 || hora == 12)) {
                            String contentText = "Você tem tarefa de " + nomeMateria + " para hoje!";
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            v.vibrate(1000);
                            showNotification(title, contentText, id, 1);
                        }
                    }
                } else if ((dateNowFormatada.compareTo(dataEntregaFormatada) == 1)) {
                    if ((hora == 15 || hora == 18 || hora == 22)) {
                        String contentText = "Você tem tarefa de " + nomeMateria + " para amanhã!";
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(1000);
                        showNotification(title, contentText, id, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
}


public void showNotification(String title, String content, int id, int tipoNotificacao) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setAutoCancel(true);;

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    if (tipoNotificacao == 1) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.homework);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TarefasActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Constantes.TAREFA_ID, String.valueOf(id));

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(TarefasActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    }

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

Mas o que acontece é que ele mostra as notificações, por exemplo, as 22h mas se eu tiro a notificaçao, ela aparece novamente! Então, é tirar que mostra novamente :/

Como resolver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para executar um serviço quando o celular for ligado tem que registar um *BroadcastReceiver* que responda à *action* `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

No *AndroidManifest.xml* registe o seu *BroadcastReceiver*:

```
<receiver android:name="aSuaPackage.StartUpBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Adicione esta permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Defina o *BroadcastReceiver* que irá lançar o seu serviço:

```
public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            // Chame aqui o seu serviço
        }
    }
}
```

No serviço defina um método para registar as notificações.
Este método usa o *AlarmManager* para lançar um *BroadcastReceiver* que irá criar as notificações na data/hora especificada no paramêtro *data*.
Chame este método por cada notificação que desejar criar.

```
private void AgendarNotificacao(Date data) {

 // Obtém um novo calendário e define a data para a data da notificação
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(data);

 // Obtém um alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

 // O id a ser usado no pending intent
    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

 // Prepara o intent que deverá ser lançado na data definida
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CriarNotificacao.class);

 // Obtém o pending intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 // Regista o alerta no sistema.
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Como você tem mais de um tipo de notificação introduza os parâmetros que necessitar para construir a notificação. Passe essa informação ao *Intent* através de `Intent.putExtra();`

Defina o *BroadcastReceiver* que será lançado pelo AlarmManager registado pelo método anterior.
Este *BroadcastReceiver* é responsável por criar a notificação.

```
public class CriarNotificacao extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {

    // Obtenha os 'Extra' que passou e crie aqui a notificação

}
```

Registe-o no *AndroidManifest.xml*.

```
<receiver android:name="aSuaPackage.CriarNotificação"/>
```

Notas:

- É necessário executar a aplicação uma vez antes de ela poder responder à `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` *action*. O mesmo se aplica caso a sua execução tenha sido parada usando *Force Close*.
- A aplicação necessita de ser instalada na memória do celular.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Fiz o que me pediu, mas não funcionou. Segue o código modificado: http://pastebin.com/fgYui4W8

Comment: Você registou o CriarNotificação no AndroidManifest.xml.? Esqueci de colocar esse pormenor na resposta.

Comment: Estive a ver o seu código e julgo que não entendeu como usar o método AgendarNotificação. Você deve passar ao método a data e hora em que quer ser notificado. Suponha que tem uma tarefa para a data 16/04/2015 às 18h e quer ser notificado 3 horas antes, deverá subtrair à data da tarefa 3 horas e chamar o método com o resultado. Use a classe *Calendar* para construir a *data* a passar ao método. Não esqueça que ao dizer *data* não me estou apenas a referir ao dia, mês e ano mas sim também à hora, minuto e segundo a que quer que a notificação seja lançada.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Assim que possível irei tentar implementar a solução xD

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!