# Monitor de arquivos android

Tags: android, arquivo

Tenho a necessidade de desenvolver um aplicativo para android onde o mesmo trabalhe monitorando um certo diretório com uma certa periodicidade e enviando novos arquivos desse diretório para um FTP ou outra pasta qualquer da rede local que o dispositivo está conectado.
Ex.: A cada dois minutos monitorar o diretório da câmera e sempre que um usuário tirar uma nova foto, esse monitor verificar se existem novas fotos e enviar para um diretório da rede local. Como trabalhar com esse tipo de app no android?

Answer (score 2):

Para monitorar alterações em uma pasta do Android use a classe [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html)

Uma possível implementação seria assim:

```
public class FileMonitor extends FileObserver {

    public MyFileObserver(String path) {

        super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

        if (path == null) {
            return;
        }

        if ((FileObserver.CREATE & event)!=0) {

            //Foi criado um novo ficheiro ou uma nova pasta.
            //Introduza aqui o código para o tratamento que quer
            //efectuar para este caso 
        }

    }

}
```

Neste exemplo apenas se está a monitorizar se foi criado um novo ficheiro ou pasta dentro da pasta monitorizada.

É possível monitorizar outros eventos, veja a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html).

Para utilizar faça:

```
FileMonitor monitor = new FileMonitor("/sdcard/minhaPasta/");
monitor.startWatching();
```

Para parar a monitorização use:

```
monitor.stopWatching();
```

Comment: ramaral, muito obrigado... tenho uma dúvida: eu preciso que o aplicativo fique rodando em background o tempo todo, na verdade ele nem precisa ter interface, ele só precisa fazer esse monitoramento... qual a maneira mais correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Crie um serviço para fazer o monitorização e defina um [BroadcastReceiver](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58040/2541) que seja chamado após o *boot* do dispositivo. O *BroadcastReceiver* será usado para iniciar o serviço.

Comment: Certo... para um melhor entendimento, neste caso o serviço vai ficar sempre em execução respeitando a classe FileMonitor ou seria necessário definir uma periodicidade para execução do mesmo? Como seria a interação entre o dois (BroadcastReceiver e classe FileMonitor )?

Comment: No serviço você cria uma instância da classe FileMonitor e chama `monitor.startWatching();`. O BroadcastReceiver será usado para iniciar o serviço.  Se criar o *BroadcastReceiver* como eu explico [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58040/2541) ele será lançando após o arranque do dispositivo e o serviço ficará sempre em execução.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará de um broadcast receiver que te dará a informação que uma nova foto foi tirada. Ou seja, sempre que uma foto for tirada você terá tal informação e chamará o código de envio para o FTP

Caso o exemplo da foto seja o seu real problema você pode tentar isto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571461/broadcast-receiver-wont-receive-camera-event

Dentro do onReceive do seu broadcast é onde você deve listar as fotos e buscar pela foto nova.