# Verificar se foi tirado uma screenshot da tela

Tags: android

O [Snapchat](https://www.snapchat.com/) possui uma funcionalidade que é notificar o usuário toda vez que alguém, um outro usuário qualquer, tira um *screenshot* de suas histórias.

A princípio pensei na hipótese de verificar se o usuário pressionou <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>, porém nada garante que o *screenshot* será salvo, pois pode não haver memória suficiente para salvar. Além disso, acredito eu que cada dispositivo pode mudar a forma de como capturar a tela, sem contar que existem outras aplicações que facilitam este processo.

Outra forma seria verificar se houve alguma alteração diretório `Screenshots`, [usando a classe `FileObserver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532862/2570426), porém também não há garantias que em todos os dispositivos esse *path* será o mesmo.

Qual seria a forma mais viável para identificar esta ação? Como posso verificar se o usuário tirou um *screenshot* no momento do uso da aplicação?

Comment: [Tá na mão](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29532862/5524514)

Comment: Ta sim @AckLay, o artigo linkado é bem explicativo e aborda muito bem a implementação e possibilidade. Se esta com dificuldade em entender a referência, então o problema não é na linguagem/funcionalidade.

Comment: @juniorb2ss Você está falando da discussão que tem um link?! Aqui não está abrindo. Mas vou ver o que pode ser.

Comment: @AckLay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532502/detect-a-screenshot-android/29532862#29532862

Comment: @juniorb2ss isso eu consigo acessar! O que não está abrindo é o link dentro desta resposta, aqui aparece que o link está quebrado.

Comment: @AckLay mas não esta quebrado, acessando normalmente.

Comment: Por algum motivo que não sei @juniorb2ss aqui está aparecendo que o link está quebrado. Enfim, baseado no que você acha que está "[..]bem explicativo e aborda muito bem a implementação e possibilidade[..]" você consegue dar uma resposta aqui no SOpt, para ficar registrado?!

Comment: Tente monitorizar o caminho `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/Screenshots/"` com o código desta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78269/2541)

Comment: @ramaral vi algo relacionado, talvez seja melhor opção. Outra opção seria capturar o evento dos click, como por exemplo botão (home+volume -), porém isso não garante que foi salvo a imagem, por exemplo, em situações de dispositivo sem memória. Vou pesquisar mais um pouco.

Comment: Também não tenho a certeza se o *path* é sempre aquele que indiquei.

Comment: Eu conheço uma maneira de 'bloquear' Screenshots, mas sei que não é bem o que tu quer. :(

Comment: Netflix usa isso, uma `view` para bloquear `gravações` ou `prints`.

Comment: @Luc não é bloquear, mas sim verificar se foi tirado um screenshot.

Comment: @acklay No mesmo link passado pelo diegofm, tem uma segunda resposta. Não conseguiu com ela? Não tenho ambiente para testar, mas fiquei curioso com a resolução desta sua pergunta.

Comment: Acho que você está complicando demais a solução. O caminho em varias perguntas do SOEn é monitorar o diretorio, se não serve, monitorar o serviço que ativa quando se tira um screenshot, se tambem não serve, então acho que a unica solução é estudar o código fonte do android.

Comment: Vai implementar um bloqueio de screenshot? um contador ?kkkkkkk dai camarada vai lá ti tira uma foto com outro dispositivo e "pá" lá se vai a integridade da coisa...rsrsrsr

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução é usar o `ContentObserver`, porque ocorrerá a inserção de um registro no database de mídia do sistema após o screenshot da tela.

Para esse método é necessária a permissão [`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Código exemplo:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("content_observer");
handlerThread.start();
final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {

@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        true,
        new ContentObserver(handler) {
            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                Log.d(TAG, "deliverSelfNotifications");
                return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                super.onChange(selfChange);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChange " + uri.toString());
                if (uri.toString().matches(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/[0-9]+")) {

                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                        }, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            final String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            final String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                            // TODO: apply filter on the file name to ensure it's screen shot event
                            Log.d(TAG, "screen shot added " + fileName + " " + path);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null)  {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            }
        }
);
```

Fonte: [Detect only screenshot with FileObserver Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621903/detect-only-screenshot-with-fileobserver-android/29624090#29624090)