# Notificação Android não funciona

Tags: android, android-notification

Segui o exemplo dado aqui do stackoverflow,

[Notificações em tempo determinado e ao ligar celular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58036/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-tempo-determinado-e-ao-ligar-celular/215579?noredirect=1#comment440451_215579)

mas só o serviço é que é iniciado, a notificação não é lançada.
Segue aqui o meu código, como resolvo esta situação?

```
public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
              context.startService(new Intent(context, 
              ShowNotificationService.class));
            }
     }
}



public class ShowNotificationService extends Service {

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
           String date_s = "2017-06-26 15:11:00";

           // *** note that it's "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
            SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
             Date date = null;
             try {
                 date = dt.parse(date_s);
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              AgendarNotificacao(date);
         }

         @Override
         public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
              return null;
         }

private void AgendarNotificacao(Date data) {

    // Obtém um novo calendário e define a data para a data da notificação
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(data);

    // Obtém um alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

    // O id a ser usado no pending intent
    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Prepare the intent which should be launched at the date
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CriarNotificacao.class);

    // Obtém o pending intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Regista o alerta no sistema.
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
}

public class CriarNotificacao extends BroadcastReceiver {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("lala")
            .setContentText("conteudo")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(1500);

    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Comment: No manifest indico o service     <service android:name=".Notification.ShowNotificationService" />

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: não, a notificação simplesmente não surge

Comment: Registou o BroadcastReceiver CriarNotificacao no AndroidManifest?

Comment: Não não registei, assim que puder testarei. Obrigado!!

Comment: Ramaral tem razão, mesmo assim ainda não funciona. Dá este erro Process: com.example, PID: 2338                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example. Notification.CriarNotificacao: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No intents added to TaskStackBuilder; cannot getPendingIntent    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No intents added to TaskStackBuilder; cannot getPendingIntent

Comment: CriarNotificacao está num arquivo java próprio(CriarNotificacao.java)?

Comment: Sim ramaral, esta

Comment: Não consigo perceber qual é o problema. Se estiver a fazer tudo como descrito na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58040/2541) à pergunta [Notificações em tempo determinado e ao ligar celular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58036/2541) deveria funcionar já que aquele código foi testado antes de responder. Para que eu possa ser notificado quando posta um comentário use @ramaral em vez de só ramaral.

Comment: @ramaral eu coloquei um log na classe criarNotificação, mesmo antes de criar a notificação, sabe me dizer porque é que este log só aparece se eu desligar o telemovel? Se eu estiver com a aplicação aberta, nada acontece, mas se eu desligar o telemovel o log aparecee logo se seguida.

Comment: Se a notificação aparece só após ligar o telemóvel é porque a data/hora da notificação já passou. Lembre também que a notificação só é agendada pelo Alarme quando ligar o telemóvel.

Comment: @ramaral peço desculpa por estar a incomodar, mas e se eu quiser que a notificação apareça também mesmo quando o telemóvel esta bloqueado, ou a aplicação aberta?

Comment: Ainda não entendi bem o que pretende fazer, no entanto veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189288/2541). Adapte-a para o seu caso.

Comment: @ramaral a qestão é, a notificação só é lançada se o telemovel for desligado? Ou é lançada mesmo que a aplicação esteja a ser executada ou o telemovel bloqueado? (referindo-me ao exemplo que segui)

Comment: A notificação só é agendada pelo Alarme quando ligar o telemóvel, logo é necessário desligar e ligar. Se quiser agendar a notificação sem desligar/ligar chame o serviço ShowNotificationService com `startService()` em uma Activity. Se agendada, a notificação será lançada quer esteja ou não a aplicação em execução. Da forma como foi feita a implementação do serviço não garanto que o telemóvel seja "acordado", se estiver bloqueado. Veja como utilizar o PowerManager no serviço BootService da resposta que eu indiquei.